# how could i playing audio in my app from my server?

Tags: android, media-player

im a new beginner in android... i dont know how can i playing audio from any server in my app.. just i can make to playin' mp3 or whatever from sdcard or raw folder.. 
someone can help me about this point ?!.. and i searched in this webpage but everyone explained something about this.. i confused all :(

Main.java

```
TextView ic=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sonraki);
ic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v){
       Intent i=new Intent(tasavvuf.this,ney.class);
       startActivity(i);


Button play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cal);
Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dur);

play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    }

     });



stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(tasavvuf.this,R.raw.tasavvuf);
    mp.start();
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as for playing mp3 from server URL :

```
 stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(Your_Activity.this, 
           Uri.parse("YOUR_MP3#_URL_HERE"));
           mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
         });
    }
```

And also add Internet Permission in `Androidmanifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: you can also checkout this example http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class in which he is playing audio from server using mediaPlayer.setDataSource .

Comment: @Mursid : can u tell me problem?means what happen when u are using this code

Comment: @Mursid : also doenload this http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/source/streamingMp3player.zip example and put your mp3 file url in EditText check it's working or not

Comment: oh cihsis chris ur re triple double king dude :) ! thx so much

Comment: @Mursid : most welcome friend !!!:) then just upvote my answer if it really help u

Comment: so how can i playing multiple mp3s :( not only one much more !any suggests ?!

Comment: @Mursid : i think it's possible using `SoundPool` so you can google for this and see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html here for more info

Answer (score 1):

Implement OnPreparedListener in your class and override onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp).

Then in your onCreate :

String url = "URL";

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

}

Do mp.start in overrided onPrepared for prepared media to start.

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

```
   mp.start();
```

}

For detailed reference you can lookout for RandomMusicPlayer example in sample android code.

Answer (score 0):

For you to play audio in Android, you need to make yourself familiar with MediaPlayer. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html.

There are also many good tutorials available online.
Try http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android
and http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Hope that helps! :)